# How do I make my added products to sub total price?

Tags: php, arrays, subtotal

How do I make my added products to total price?

Meaning I did some code to sub some products prices but it doesn't work?!

It just print on last product the total which I want to be sub all products

Here's the code:

function.php

```
    function display_payers(){

    $total = 0;
    $category_query = query("SELECT * FROM payers WHERE payers_id  " . escape_string($id) . " ");
    confirm($category_query);
    
    while ($row = fetch_array($category_query)) {
 
        $sub             = $row['price'];
        $payers_id       = $row['payers_id'];
        $name            = $row['name'];
        $serial_number   = $row['serial_number'];
        $mobile_number   = $row['mobile_number'];
        $email           = $row['email'];
        $pass            = $row['pass'];
        $price           = $row['price'];
        
        $payer_photo = $row['payer_photo']; //**** */
        $user_show = $row['user_show']; //**** */
 
 
        $payer = <<<DELIMETER
        
        
        <tr>
        <td>{$payers_id}</td>
        <td>{$name}</td>
         <td>{$serial_number}</td>
         <td>{$mobile_number},<br>{$email},<br>{$pass}</td>
         <td>{$user_show}<br>
         <a>
             <img style="width: 80px; height="80px" src="../../resources/uploads/$payer_photo" alt="">
         </a>
     </td>
     <td>{$price}SR<br>
     </td>
         <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-number" href="index.php?edit_payer&id={$row['payers_id']}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
 
         <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php?delete_payers_id={$row['payers_id']}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
DELIMETER;
 
        echo $payer;
    }
 
    $_SESSION['item_totals'] = $total += $sub;
}
```

Comment: Add `$_SESSION['item_totals'] += $sub;` just below `echo $player;` ie inside the while loop

Comment: i did and it tells me this Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xamp\htdocs\resources\functions.php on line 1099

Comment: Where is the variable `escape_string($id)`

Comment: i delete it and the problem solved. thanks

Comment: can you tell me how can i sub two numbers and minus them and gives me value of that minus?

Comment: I didnt get your question , could you please explain with an example

Comment: like if i want to put number product 2 +product  2 = 4 which is i did it ealiar above.. and then on the other hand this result 4 want to put another num like 1 to minus 4 - 1 = 3 so how can i do this on my code above after sub

Answer (score 1):

Use this to add subtotal

```
$_SESSION['item_totals'] += $sub;
```

To subtract

```
$_SESSION['item_totals'] -= $sub_value;
```